# How does Ubuntu keep playing sounds through the TTY?

Tags: sound, tty

Occasionally, I have some music playing in the background of some of my work. When I switch to a TTY, my music/sounds/whatever continue, provided I'm logged in.

How can audio be channeled through a TTY, especially only when I'm logged in to my account? Secondly, is there a way I can disable this audio passthrough for whatever reason?

Comment: Well, it doesn't allow sound through on my machine unless something had gone wrong and my whole system is crashing...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Weird...

Comment: Well, for me it works - I listen to music through Clementine and when I switch to TTY, the sound persists.

Comment: I found you can control your player via TTY. E.g. `clementine -t` you can pause the music. And if you want to turn the sound off, use `alsamixer`

Comment: Has anyone figured this out? I'm trying to write my own X startup scripts and even when I chown+chmod the X tty audio only plays on TTYs I have logged into via text.